# Removing selector tag in Angular 5

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular5, selector

I have this HTML file that I called by using the selector tag when a button is clicked.

This function in my TS will be triggered when a button is clicked where the variable will be set as `TRUE`. If it is `TRUE` then the `*ngIf` in my HTML will do the work to show the other HTML page.

```
OpenMyNotes(){ this.MyNotesOpened = true; }
```

In my HTML is set like this :

```
<page-open-mynotes *ngIf="MyNotesOpened == true"></page-open-mynotes>
```

---

In my `page-open-mynotes` will have a dismiss button :

```
<button ion-button (click)="dismissMyNotes()">
   <ion-icon name="close" class="text-white"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

The thing is, I'm trying to remove the `page-open-mynotes` from my page when the dismiss button is clicked but it cannot be done by using the same variable `this.MyNotesOpened` from the parent page to set it back to `FALSE`. Is it possible to do a sharing variable to both pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using an EventEmitter. Do it this way.

In your parent component implement a method. Call it, for instance, `onDismissNotes()`. This method changes `this.MyNotesOpened` to `false`, whenever it is called.

```
onDismissNotes(event: any){
     this.MyNotesOpened = false;
}
```

This method gets called by EventEmitter from the child component `page-open-mynotes`.

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() private dismissMe = new EventEmitter<string>();


private dismissMyNotes(): void {
   // send a unique value, every time you fire the emitter.
   // Otherwise it may happen, that the Emitter fires only once.
   // And as the value doesn't matter in the parent component
   // UTC-time is the best you can choose.
   this.dismissMe.emit(new Date().getTime().toString());
}
```

This method get called by the HTML-template of your child component

```
<button ion-button (click)="dismissMyNotes()">
   <ion-icon name="close" class="text-white"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

And in the HTML of your parent component you do the following

```
<page-open-mynotes *ngIf="MyNotesOpened == true" (dismissMe)="onDismissNotes($event)"></page-open-mynotes>
```

Now, whenever you click `dismissMyNotes()` in the child component, the parent component gets informed and sets `this.MyNotesOpened` to `false`.
This triggers the `*ngIf` and your child component gets dismissed.